# Ruby: Is there a way to capture keypresses and the timing between them in ruby

Tags: ruby, timestamp, keyevent

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user to enter a password and then measures the timing between each keystroke after they have entered it. Is this possible?

Comment: What OS are you using? There is a simple solution for Linux.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh Mac Lion, but I would like it to be compatible on Windows, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In so far as you can ask Ruby to give you raw i/o and then get the time stamp after each read returns, yes you can. If you really need very high precision though, ruby itself will add some microseconds of latency.

Presuming that is not a problem, do something like getting a raw file descriptor for /dev/tty, use ioctls to set it for raw mode, and use the read method to get each character as it is entered. This is, of course, messy, but what you are asking for is hard to do in a non-messy manner. (It is also not portable between OSes, but it is portable across versions of Unix. You will not be able to do precisely the same thing on Windows, you'll need different code for that.)

Comment: I need millisecond accuracy, so latency isn't a big issue unless its in the microsecond range. Can I get raw IO while the user types their password in? Do I used STDIN?

Comment: ms accuracy should be doable. STDIN is generally cooked, not raw. You will need to get your own file descriptor that is safe to ioctl to raw mode. I'd open /dev/tty for input on my own to avoid messing up STDIN for the entire program, though you could just get the fd for STDIN and revert it back after the password is entered.

Comment: Wow, that's intense, for my level. I'm trying to avoid using Java Swing, thought I was a relatively decent Ruby programmer (on a general level) but now I'm having second thoughts. Is getting my own file descriptor akin to creating my own instance of IO. Could you mention some topics I could research to see how this is handled. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: Getting a file descriptor is not too hard -- everything I've discussed here ends up being a few calls. For example, see IO::sysopen to get your hands on a file descriptor for /dev/tty, IO#ioctl for a the way to do the needed ioctls, IO#sysread for the way to do a direct read. The needed ioctls will be described in a linux "termios" man page or some such. It will take you a while to put everything together, but in the end this is maybe five lines of code.

Comment: There also seems to be a ruby-termios module here https://github.com/arika/ruby-termios but I have never used it and can't speak to whether it is useful or not. Everything it does could be done in pure ruby I think -- you're doing very little.

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard way is to use the library `curses`. To get a key press, you can use the method [`getch`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-getch). You should insert `Time.now` right after `getch` to get the time immediately after the key was pressed. By doing subtraction with the time of the previous key press, you can get the duration.